# How to link my web page to social networking sites

Tags: html

I have designed my Web page using HTML5 in dreamweaver and in that I want to link my web page with social networking sites (Facebook, twitter and Linkedin).

Please tell me how to link with this and what are the plugins used to link Social Networking sites.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook's Like Button:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Twitter's Tweet Button:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button

Google+'s +1 Button:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/

AddThis is a nice way to include social buttons to your site:
https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing

Answer (score 0):

you can just show social networking icon images and give below path as a href

Facebook : http://www.facebook.com/pages/UR PAGE NAME

twitter :  https://twitter.com/#!/UR PAGE NAME

Google+ : https://plus.google.com/UR PROFILE NO.

Note: first open your social web page in browser and check the url what is provided and then copy paste that url in your social site image